# スプレッドシートのQUERY関数における複数シートの指定方法

Tags: google-spreadsheet

#### 実現したい事

1月度、2月度、・・・、12月度の各シート（項目数・項目名は同じ）に対して
QUERY関数を使用してデータを抽出したいです。

#### 問題点

```
=QUERY({'1月度'！A1:D;'2月度'！A1:D;・・・；'12月度'！A1:D}, SELECT A, C, D WHERE D = "XXXX")
```

などとしてもエラーが出てしまいます。

#### 試した事

```
=QUERY('1月度'！A1:D, SELECT A, C, D WHERE D = "XXXX")
```

といったように一つのシートに対しては動作しました。

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECTで指定する列をA,B,C,Dの代わりにCol1,Col2,Col3,Col4にしてみてください。

```
=QUERY({'1月度'!A1:D;'2月度'!A1:D}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col4 WHERE Col4 = 'XXXX'")
```

[【GAS】QUERY関数を使って複数シートの情報を統合する](https://qiita.com/ShishidoToru/items/e2b991fbf0f63710141c)を参考に試してみたところうまくいきました。

---

ドキュメントエディタヘルプで「col1　識別子」を検索したところ[Named Range?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2176851?hl=en)が見つかりました。

QUERYでは、列名はだめなようです、単一のシートだとうまくいくのが謎ですが。
なお、Colに続く数字は範囲先頭が1になるので、範囲がB列から始まる場合はB列が`Col1`になるようです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

教えていただいた事を試してみて、エラーは出なくなりました。
ですが、1月度の下に2月度の分析結果は出て来ず、
1月度の結果のみが表示される結果となりました。

ちなみに、当然かもしれませんが、
SELECT句に2月度に対応するColを足すと、行方向には結果が表示されました。

列方向に結果を表示はできないのでしょうか。

Comment: akira ejiriさま
申し訳ありません。
シート同士を繋ぐ記述で、セミコロンとすべきところを
コンマにしてしまっていました。
セミコロンに変更したところ、2月以降の月の分も縦に結合されるようになりました。
たすかりました。

Comment: @sibanban うまくいって良かったです。よろしければ回答の承認をお願いします。承認していただければうれしいです。回答の左側にあるチェックマークをチェックすると承認ができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
不慣れで申し訳ありません。。。
大変助かりました。
また機会があればよろしくお願いいたします。